# have join multiple table and get the output in DataRow in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

HI,

I have a scenario where i have join multiple table and get the output in DataRow(All the Rows return by the query).

SQL Query:

```
SELECT  Fr.InterCodeId   
        FROM    
        CodeShareInterline Fr,    
        Airline A,Zone Z   #
        WHERE    
        A.AirlineId = Fr.AirlineId   
        And Fr.ContractId=Z.ContractId
```

I know how to perform join in LINQ but how can i select all the column(Rows) in select statement of LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from fr in dataContext.CodeShareInterline
            from a in dataContext.AirLine
            from z in dataContext.Zone
            where a.AirlineId == fr.AirlineId && fr.ContractId == z.ContractId
            select new 
               {
                   Interline = fr,
                   AirLine = a,
                   Zone = z
               };
```

The anonymous type contains all data you want, you can easily visit one column by:

```
result.FirstOrDefault().Zone.SomeField
```

Comment: I think in both your solutions you are missing his requirement, projection into DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but something close to this should work. Assuming your data context is call Context. This is a translation of what you have above.

```
var o = from fr in Context.CodeShareInterline
            join a from Context.Airline on a.AirlineId == fr.AirlineId 
            join z from Context.Zone on fr.ContactId == z.ContactId
            select fr.InterCodeId;
```

If you want to select all of the data then you need to do something like this.

```
var o = from fr in Context.CodeShareInterline
            join a from Context.Airline on a.AirlineId == fr.AirlineId 
            join z from Context.Zone on fr.ContactId == z.ContactId
            select new { 
                        Interline = fr,
                        AirLine = a,
                        Zone = z
                       };
```